# Convert wireless keyboard to wired

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, usb, keyboard

I don't know if it's a silly question or not.

I'm not in anyway an engineer, not by miles.

Here's what I have:

1. Logitech MK320 keyboard with missing receiver.
2. Rapoo wireless keyboard, with working receiver but damaged keyboard.
3. One broken wired keyboard.

I'm not trying to be fancy or anything else, but it strikes me that these junks(?) has some good components to work with.

I tought of 2 scenarios:

1. Somehow sync up Rapoo receiver and Logitech keyboard.
2. Somehow make the wireless Logitech keyboard to wired.

For solution #1, I did some googling and find both manufacturer uses 2.4 GHZ frequency, but no idea about how to sync the channel.
For solution #2, I found out that if a USB cable connected to wireless keyboard, it can receive power from that USB cable instead of battery. But the keyboard still needs the receiver to translate it's input.

I don't know even if it's possible, but I'm curious about this so any input will be awesome.

Comment: Just spend $15 and buy a new keyboard. ;)  As-is, this is more of an electronics engineering question than a PC question (IMO), which is off-topic for SU.

Comment: Not possible and pointless. sorry not trying to be a jerk but you cant sync different wireless devices unless you somehow changed the wireless chip from the broken keyboard to the working one but it would be a headache even if it worked. Just buy a new one.

Comment: @Vdub I don't mind. This question is more about my personal curiousity rather than me not having a keyboard. Thanks for your input anyway! :)

Comment: @SamuelAdam - Personal curiosity is fine.  It just needs to be about something that is on topic here at Superuser.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, I did lookup where to ask about hardware question in SE, and I must have misinterpret [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=X2UYVIzEMpOOuASbz4GIDg&url=http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76731/where-do-i-ask-hardware-related-questions&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNHygLX0C80hw3dvs83vwQF0VWNnKg). It's my bad, thanks for your input! :)

Comment: Scenario #2 is technically possible, but I wouldn't try that unless the Logitech keyboard had good mechanical switches. Recycling a membrane keyboard is usually not a good idea as it will cost more than its price.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm not in anyway an engineer, not by miles.

Then you might have some trouble doing this yourself. The Rapoo and Logitech keyboards very likely use different protocols to communicate to the receiver, and so you would have to intercept that, decipher it, and then modify the firmware of the receiver or keyboard to broadcast using that new protocol, which is non-trivial because it probably means modifying the electronics themselves.

Converting a wireless keyboard to wired might be possible, but again, you would have to find the electrical schematics for the keyboard, and figure out where to attach the multiple wires inside keyboard cable onto the keyboard. There aren't really any guides out there for this kind of thing, and finding the schematics, or figuring them out yourself will be very difficult or impossible to do.

If you are an electrical engineer, and you can find the schematics for the keyboard, by all means explore and try this out, but without some in-depth technical knowledge and background with how keyboard work, this isn't going to be something you can do.

Comment: They are likely the same protocols provided both are Bluetooth/2.4hz receivers.  The  problem is the communication between the mouse and the receiver is encrypted.